# Can't run Eclipse Helios

Tags: java, eclipse

I have successfully installed **Eclipse Helios** and **Java 10.0.1**, but I can't make a program because the compiler is getting errors like this

[image: errors]
 I also tried reinstalling, and now I have multiple JREs and JDKs.

Comment: You need to download the latest version of Eclipse. Eclipse Helios is years old and doesn't even support Java 9. And in SO questions, don't post screenshots - only post code and errors as text.

Comment: You need Eclipse Oxygen.3a (4.7.3) to fully support Java 10. Helios is far too old to run with it at all.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you want to work with eclipse Helios and java 10 ? On one hand you are taking the latest version of java and on the other, very old version of eclipse. There will be compatibility issues. Please download the latest eclipse which is Oxygen from the below link.

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/oxygen2

Now, they have even released photon eclipse. Also, for oxygen you need atleast jdk 8. So set up the variables accordingly.

Hope it helps.